# Start playing streaming audio on symbian

Tags: symbian, s60, pys60

The tiny question is:

How to start (realplayer ?) playing given online resourse (e.g. http://example.com/file.mp3)

PyS60, C++ or C# via RedFiveLabs would do.

**EDIT1**: Title changed from "Start RealPlayer on symbian" to the more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the title is a little misleading if you just want to play back media content and not use a particular application for it.

In C++ there is `CMdaAudioPlayerUtility::OpenUrlL()` but it's not widely implemented. For example in S60 it will complete with `KErrNotSupported` status. To play files you can use other open functions in `CMdaAudioPlayerUtility` such as `OpenFileL()` or `OpenDesL()` but you need a separate mechanism for retrieving the files or at least the bytes onto the device.

There is also `CVideoPlayerUtility::OpenUrlL()` which supports `rtsp` audio streams but not `http`.

Comment: Thank you. The title is now changed.

Comment: Do you know how to play mp3 audio by downloading a file on your own and feeding it to some API?

Comment: Yes, use the HTTP client APIs (e.g. `RHTTPTransaction`) for download and `CMdaAudioPlayerUtility` for playback as described above.